# Have Highcharts fill available height

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to get Highcharts to expand vertically to fill up available space. I can't seem to figure it out though. Here's the demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/9xa4unka/

Is it possible to get Highcharts to expand `#container` to fill the height **without defining a height on `#rail`** (the height of `#rail` is dynamic)?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/9xa4unka/2/